# Calling Java Method HttpServletResponse in flex 4

Tags: java, servlets, flex4

I have a service class that creates reports in xls using dynamicjasper, I wonder how I can include a button in my flex app to execute this method.

```
@Service("downloadService")
@Transactional
public class DownServiceRelTemp {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

    @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void downloadXLS(HttpServletResponse response) throws ColumnBuilderException,
        ClassNotFoundException, JRException {

        logger.debug("Downloading Excel report");

        DynamicReport dr = LayouteRelTemp.buildReportLayout();
        JRDataSource ds = getDataSource();
        JasperReport jr = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), null);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, ds);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Exporter.exportToXLS(jp, baos);
        String fileName = "MyReport.xls";
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        Writer.write(response, baos);
    }
```

Any suggestions, do not have much experience with adobe flex and would like a simple help.

Answer (score 0):

There's some ways to interactive flex with java

1. Using Web Services
2. Using servlets
3. By Remoting objects. By AMF thecnology.

I recommend this [tutorial](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/02/23/flex-4-and-java-basics-video/) of the evangelist James Ward, in this tutorial him explains the differents ways to connect flex and java with code example. That's how I learned to comunicate flex and Java

Notes that you need to check [blazeDs](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) Library

Comment: Thanks George. I'll take a look at this tutorial. James Ward is a great expert in Flex.